# Display some images on gridview and flipview

Tags: c#, json, gridview, uwp, flipview

I have a gridview that contains some images with XAML and code below:

XAML:

```
<ProgressRing x:Name="busyIndicator" Margin="10,0,10,10" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="45" Height="45"/>
         <GridView x:Name="ImageGridView" Margin="15,100,10,0" Height="600" Width="1200" ItemsSource="{x:Bind listingDatasourceDetail}" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemDetailScrollViewer" DataContext="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=itemListView}"
                              ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Auto" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                              ScrollViewer.ZoomMode="Disabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ItemClick="ImageGridView_ItemClick" SelectionChanged="ImageGridView_SelectionChanged" >
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:ListingClass">
                <Grid Height="320" Width="250" Margin="10,0,0,0" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="#FF646464" BorderThickness="1">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Image x:Name="cover1" Grid.Column="0" Source="{Binding ImageURL1}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Stretch="Uniform" AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding Title}"/>
                        <Image x:Name="cover2" Grid.Column="1" Source="{Binding ImageURL2}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Stretch="Uniform" AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding Title}"/>
                        <Image x:Name="cover3" Grid.Column="2" Source="{Binding ImageURL3}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Stretch="Uniform" AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding Title}"/>
                        <Image x:Name="cover4" Grid.Column="3" Source="{Binding ImageURL4}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Stretch="Uniform" AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding Title}"/>
                        <Image x:Name="cover5" Grid.Column="4" Source="{Binding ImageURL5}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Stretch="Uniform" AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding Title}"/>
                        <Image x:Name="cover6" Grid.Column="5" Source="{Binding ImageURL6}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Stretch="Uniform" AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding Title}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemTemplate>

            <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <ItemsWrapGrid Orientation="Vertical" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemsPanel>
        </GridView>
```

Code:

```
public async void Listing()
        {
            try
            {
                busyIndicator.IsActive = true;
                string urlPath = "http://.../API/detail";
                var httpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler());

                var values = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
                    {
                        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("api_key", "b1729409..."),
                        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("id-sekolah", "60400172")

                    };

                var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(urlPath, new FormUrlEncodedContent(values));
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                string jsonText = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                JsonObject jsonObject = JsonObject.Parse(jsonText);
                JsonObject jsonData = jsonObject["data"].GetObject();

                JsonObject groupObject1 = jsonData.GetObject();

                string id = groupObject1["id"].GetString();
                string title = groupObject1["nama"].GetString();
                string urlImage1 = groupObject1.ContainsKey("img_1") && groupObject1["img_1"] != null ? groupObject1["img_1"].GetString() : string.Empty;
                string urlImage2 = groupObject1.ContainsKey("img_2") && groupObject1["img_2"] != null ? groupObject1["img_2"].GetString() : string.Empty;
                string urlImage3 = groupObject1.ContainsKey("img_3") && groupObject1["img_3"] != null ? groupObject1["img_3"].GetString() : string.Empty;
                string urlImage4 = groupObject1.ContainsKey("img_4") && groupObject1["img_4"] != null ? groupObject1["img_4"].GetString() : string.Empty;
                string urlImage5 = groupObject1.ContainsKey("img_5") && groupObject1["img_5"] != null ? groupObject1["img_5"].GetString() : string.Empty;
                string urlImage6 = groupObject1.ContainsKey("img_6") && groupObject1["img_6"] != null ? groupObject1["img_6"].GetString() : string.Empty;

                ListingClass file = new ListingClass();
                file.ID = Int32.Parse(id);
                file.Title = title;
                file.ImageURL1 = urlImage1;
                file.ImageURL2 = urlImage2;
                file.ImageURL3 = urlImage3;
                file.ImageURL4 = urlImage4;

                listingDatasourceDetail.Add(file);
                ImageGridView.ItemsSource = listingDatasourceDetail;
                busyIndicator.IsActive = false;
            }
```

And when the user clicks the image on the gridview, it will show a flipview with a larger image with XAML and the code below:

XAML:

```
<StackPanel x:Name="listingFullImageDetailBox" Margin="0,0,10,10" Height="auto" Visibility="Collapsed">
            <ProgressRing x:Name="listingDetailLoading" Margin="10,0,10,10" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="45" Height="45"/>
            <Grid x:Name="listingFullImageDetailGrid" BorderBrush="#FF990000" BorderThickness="1">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <AppBarButton x:Name="closeListingFullImageBtn" Grid.Column="1" Icon="Clear" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Foreground="Black" Click="closeListingFullImageBtn_Click"/>
               <FlipView x:Name="listingImageFullFlipview" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,0,0,0" ItemsSource="{x:Bind listingDatasourceDetail}" SelectedIndex="{Binding ElementName=ImageGridView, Path=SelectedIndex, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="650" Height="500" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Background="{x:Null}">
                <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:ListingClass">
                            <Grid x:Name="content" Margin="0,0,0,0">
                                <Image x:Name="cover1" Source="{Binding ImageURLFull1}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Stretch="Uniform" AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding ID}"/>
                                <Image x:Name="cover2" Source="{Binding ImageURLFull2}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Stretch="Uniform" AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding ID}"/>
                                <Image x:Name="cover3" Source="{Binding ImageURLFull3}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Stretch="Uniform" AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding ID}"/>
                                <Image x:Name="cover4" Source="{Binding ImageURLFull4}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Stretch="Uniform" AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding ID}"/>
                                <Image x:Name="cover5" Source="{Binding ImageURLFull5}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Stretch="Uniform" AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding ID}"/>
                                <Image x:Name="cover6" Source="{Binding ImageURLFull6}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Stretch="Uniform" AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding ID}"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </FlipView.ItemTemplate>
                </FlipView>
            </Grid>
        </StackPanel>
```

Code:

```
private async void ImageGridView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                busyIndicator.IsActive = true;
                string urlPath = "http://.../API/detail";
                var httpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler());

                var values = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
                    {
                        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("api_key", "b1729409..."),
                        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("id-sekolah", "60400172")

                    };

                var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(urlPath, new FormUrlEncodedContent(values));
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                string jsonText = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                JsonObject jsonObject = JsonObject.Parse(jsonText);
                JsonObject jsonData = jsonObject["data"].GetObject();

                JsonObject groupObject1 = jsonData.GetObject();

                string id = groupObject1["id"].GetString();
                string title = groupObject1["nama"].GetString();
                string urlImage1 = groupObject1.ContainsKey("img_1") && groupObject1["img_1"] != null ? groupObject1["img_1"].GetString() : string.Empty;
                string urlImage2 = groupObject1.ContainsKey("img_2") && groupObject1["img_2"] != null ? groupObject1["img_2"].GetString() : string.Empty;
                string urlImage3 = groupObject1.ContainsKey("img_3") && groupObject1["img_3"] != null ? groupObject1["img_3"].GetString() : string.Empty;
                string urlImage4 = groupObject1.ContainsKey("img_4") && groupObject1["img_4"] != null ? groupObject1["img_4"].GetString() : string.Empty;
                string urlImage5 = groupObject1.ContainsKey("img_5") && groupObject1["img_5"] != null ? groupObject1["img_5"].GetString() : string.Empty;
                string urlImage6 = groupObject1.ContainsKey("img_6") && groupObject1["img_6"] != null ? groupObject1["img_6"].GetString() : string.Empty;

                ImageGridView.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                listingFullImageDetailBox.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                listingDetailLoading.IsActive = true;

                ObservableCollection<ListingClass> imageinfos = new ObservableCollection<ListingClass>();
                ListingClass info = new ListingClass();
                info.ImageURLFull1 = new BitmapImage(new Uri(urlImage1));
                info.ImageURLFull2 = new BitmapImage(new Uri(urlImage2));
                info.ImageURLFull3 = new BitmapImage(new Uri(urlImage3));
                info.ImageURLFull4 = new BitmapImage(new Uri(urlImage4));
                imageinfos.Add(info);

                listingImageFullFlipview.ItemsSource = imageinfos;
                var listingImageFlipview = (GridView)sender;
                listingImageFullFlipview.SelectedIndex = listingImageFlipview.SelectedIndex;
                listingDetailLoading.IsActive = false;
            }
}
```

ListingClass:

```
class ListingClass
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        public string Title { get; set; }

        public string ImageURL1 { get; set; }

        public string ImageURL2 { get; set; }

        public string ImageURL3 { get; set; }

        public string ImageURL4 { get; set; }

        public string ImageURL5 { get; set; }

        public string ImageURL6 { get; set; }

        public ImageSource ImageURLFull1 { get; set; }

        public ImageSource ImageURLFull2 { get; set; }

        public ImageSource ImageURLFull3 { get; set; }

        public ImageSource ImageURLFull4 { get; set; }

        public ImageSource ImageURLFull5 { get; set; }

        public ImageSource ImageURLFull6 { get; set; }
    }
```

I want to show all the images on the gridview (4 to 6 images corresponding to the image provided on JSON). And after the user selects the image, it will show the image on the flipview.
I'm having trouble, that is, it can only show the first index only on the gridview. And in flipview the displayed image does not match the user's selected image on the gridview and the image can not be shifted. How to handle it?

JSON:

```
"img_1": "http://sekolah.pendidikan.id/gb/1-60400172.jpg",
"img_2": "http://sekolah.pendidikan.id/gb/2-60400172.jpg",
"img_3": "http://sekolah.pendidikan.id/gb/3-60400172.jpg",
"img_4": "http://sekolah.pendidikan.id/gb/4-60400172.jpg",
"img_5": "",
"img_6": "",
```

Comment: If I am right you are having the same Items on `GridView` and `FlipView`. Am I right?

Comment: yes, the gridview and flipview have same items

Comment: Then why don't you set the `listingFullImageDetailGrid.SelectedIndex = ImageGridView.SelectedIndex` in `ImageGridView_SelectionChanged` Vice Versa

Comment: @VijayNirmal I've added listingFullImageDetailGrid.SelectedIndex = ImageGridView.SelectedIndex to ImageGridView_SelectionChanged , but the error message appears: https://1drv.ms/i/s!Auqiv8Ukng7U7mHGqqoIIY6LJgvy
How to solve the image display on the gridview only 1 and display images on the flipview that can not be shifted (move to the image before or after)?

Comment: Does this error only appear when the `GridView` contains only one Item?  Check for `null` in `listingImageFlipview.SelectedIndex`. Also, you don't want to use `SelectedItem="{Binding gallery, Mode=TwoWay}"` when you use the above method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have same elements in `GridView` and `FlipView`, Have a single `ItemsSource` list this can reduce your code also you don't want to call the same API to go the same Image.

To change the `FlipView` corresponding to `GridView` Selected Item, you can use `SelectedIndex="{Binding ElementName=MyGridView, Path=SelectedIndex, Mode=TwoWay}"`

**Sample Code:**

```
<GridView x:Name="MyGridView" ItemsSource="{x:Bind ItemsSourceCollection}">
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:ItemSource">
            <!-- Your Code -->
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>

<FlipView ItemsSource="{x:Bind ItemsSourceCollection}" SelectedIndex="{Binding ElementName=MyGridView, Path=SelectedIndex, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:ItemSource">
            <!-- Your Code -->
        </DataTemplate>
    </FlipView.ItemTemplate>
</FlipView>
```

**Sample Output:**

[image]

---

Set `ItemsSource` of both `GridView` and `FlipView` to `listingDatasourceDetail` and use below code to Add item to it.

```
string id = groupObject1["id"].GetString();
string title = groupObject1["nama"].GetString();

for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++)
{
    if (groupObject1[$"img_{i}"] != null && groupObject1.ContainsKey($"img_{i}") && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(groupObject1[$"img_{i}"].GetString()))
    {
        listingDatasourceDetail.Add(new ListingClass
        {
            ID = id,
            Title = title,
            ImageURL = new BitmapImage(new Uri(groupObject1[$"img_{i}"].GetString()))
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: @Rose You have to change the `ItemsSource` to yours and same with `x:DataType`. Above code is just a sample. Also, I have attached Sample Output

Comment: I have changed ItemSource to ItemsSource = "{x: Bind listingDatasourceDetail}" and x: DataType becomes x: DataType = "local: ListingClass", but the data displayed on the gridview remains only 1 and on the flipview can not be shifted. How to handle it? Note: I have changed the code in the post above.

Comment: What do you mean by "data displayed on the gridview remains only 1"? Do you mean the `GridView` contains only one element (or) GridView selection doesn't affect the `FlipView`?

Comment: I have 4 to 6 images (depending on the JSON data), but the image that was successfully displayed on the gridview is only 1. Please notice the JSON I posted above.

Comment: @Rose I will get back to you soon. I am kind of Busy

Comment: Vijay Nirmal: ok. I will waiting for you

Comment: If you want to display 4 to 6 image in `GridView` then you don't want to use 6 `<Image/>` in `GridView.ItemTemplate` just use only one and Store every image as a new item in `listingDatasourceDetail`. Currently, in your code, there is no use for `GridView` because you already defined all the `Image` there is no need to repeat it. I think you didn't understand the use of `DataTemplate`, You can learn here: [DataTemplate Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.DataTemplate)

Comment: If using 1 <image /> on gridview, then it can only display img_1 only. I need to display 4-6 images according to the data on JSON (img_1, img_2, img_3, img_4, img_5, img_6). Img data on JSON is a list image (not an array). How to handle it?

Comment: @Rose If you use `GridView.ItemTemplate` it automatically repeats the `DataTemplate` to the number of elements in the `List`

Comment: I've used 1 <image /> on the DataTemplate, but can only display 1 image on gridview and flipview. How to handle it? Full project: https://1drv.ms/u/s!Auqiv8Ukng7U7mM2ShLTKpu-haqz

Comment: @Rose I have corrected everything. Get your code from [here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AhsM8UnfYgSDh9NSCg4E9P_9QVFrMQ). I strongly recommend you to go through my code before doing anything.

Comment: @Rose What happened?

Comment: thank you, it's working. Sorry for delayed respond because yesterday is national holiday in my country

Comment: @Rose Great, Consider Mark as Answer and UpVote